# "contextlib.redirect_stdout" not working on Ipython

Tags: python

I am working on Ipython like to get help info about `os.stat` and redirect the output to a plain markdown file:

```
In [57]: with contextlib.redirect_stdout(open("stat_help_docs.md", "w")):
    ...:     help(os.stat)
    ...:     
In [58]: os.stat("stat_help_docs.md").st_size
Out[58]: 1
```

The "stat_help_docs.md" is empty, it failed to write help docs to it.
However, If I tried in the Standard Python Interactive Mode:

```
>>> import os
>>> import contextlib
>>> with contextlib.redirect_stdout(open("another_stat_help_docs.md", "w")):
...     help(os.stat)
... 
>>> os.stat("another_stat_help_docs.md").st_size
919
```

It succeeded in write to the file.
I assume the problem might lie in the setting of Ipython,
Could please provide any hints to help dig in the problem?

Comment: Presumably IPython redirects help to either stderr or /dev/tty instead of stdout. Do you see the help pop up interactively, or does it just silently do nothing?

Comment: Meanwhile, is there a reason you can't just `f.write(os.stat.__doc__)` instead of trying to capture it from stdout? IIRC, the only thing `help` adds is the signature on top, and you can always write that first, then write the docstring, if you really need that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need flush the file write buffer:

```
In [9]: f = open('stat_help_docs.txt', 'w')


In [10]: with contextlib.redirect_stdout(f):
    ...:     help(os.stat)

In [11]: os.stat("stat_help_docs.txt").st_size
Out[11]: 0

In [12]: f.flush()

In [13]: os.stat("stat_help_docs.txt").st_size
Out[13]: 919
```

In the standard python shell, the file object gets recycled right after `with` context and the underlying write buffer is flushed, no idea why IPython shell holds extra references for the file object.

But IMO one shouldn't rely on GC to flush the write buffer, either use file obj as a context manager (`with open('...'):`) or flush explicitly.